# UIWebView strange behavior on different devices

Tags: ios, memory, uiwebview

I have developed a sample iPad application in which I open the one file of type ppt in UIWebView. When I run this application on iPad having O.S version 5.0(iPad2) & 4.3.1(iPad1) the application gets crash with following error(Memory Warning):

```
Apr 11 11:01:23 unknown WebViewTest[345] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Apr 11 11:01:24 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Apr 11 11:01:24 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[0x3072]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:24 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.extentia.DMG[0x6ba7]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:24 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'Settings' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:24 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'DMG' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:25 unknown ReportCrash[347] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-04-11-110125.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Apr 11 11:01:25 unknown WebViewTest[345] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Apr 11 11:01:26 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Apr 11 11:01:26 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.extentia.WebViewTest[0x99f4]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:26 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Apr 11 11:01:26 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'WebViewTest' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 11 11:01:35 unknown ReportCrash[348] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-04-11-110135.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

But when I run same application on iPad having O.S version 4.3.3(iPad2) it runs perfectly. What is the reason behind this strange behavior & any solution to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a Real device. No problem with simulator.

Answer (score -1):

your app is crashing because it ran out of memory.
Try using PDF format or PPS (power point slide show) format. That may take some lesser space.

Comment: Ya I know its memory problem. But But same file gets open in the application which is present in the App store, which is specially designed for opening the ppt files. It works perfectly in that.

Comment: when a PDF file is loaded, whole file is not loaded into memory, only required pages are loaded. May be they are handling the PPTs in same way to reduce memory foot print. As you said its a dedicated app, may be they are processing the file manually instead of loading it into webview.